# Mixing native code with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm just learning React Native for a cross platform app I am building.

I just need to know if it is (a) possible (b) supported (c) relatviely simple to mix native, platform specific code (java, swift, objc, etc.) into a react native project.

I want to do some pretty specific things with camera/hardware that will require writing some native code.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction or at least tell me that what I want to do is supported by React Native before I dive in too far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes to a, b, and c. See the official guides for [iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) and [Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html).

Comment: thank you! I'm sure I could have found these links myself, but I appreciate you taking the time.